# Why does pd.date_range return an empty sequence?

Tags: python, pandas

pd.date_range is not accepting string variables for start and end date.
I am getting my start and end date as variables from another dataframe:

```
start_date = yoy_traffic_df['dt'].iloc[0]
end_date = yoy_traffic_df['dt'].iloc[-1]

print(yoy_traffic_df['dt'].iloc[[0, -1]].to_dict())
{0: '2018-09-14', 5567: '2018-03-28'}
```

The start_date and end_date are type string:

```
print(type(start_date),type(end_date))
<class 'str'> <class 'str'>

print(end_date,start_date)
2018-09-14 2018-03-28

dates = pd.Series(pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq='D'))
Series([], dtype: datetime64[ns])
```

If I set the variables as specific dates it pd.date_range gives the wanted output

```py
start_date = '2018-03-28'
end_date = '2018-09-14'

d = pd.Series(pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq='D'))
d.head()

0   2018-03-28
1   2018-03-29
2   2018-03-30
3   2018-03-31
4   2018-04-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

The expected output is a series.head() like

```
0   2018-03-28
1   2018-03-29
2   2018-03-30
3   2018-03-31
4   2018-04-01
```

Comment: Show us what `yoy_traffic_df['dt']` looks like, we can help you then.

Comment: Can you print `start_date` and `end_date`?

Comment: @harvpan added the print for start_date and end_date

Comment: @cs95 yoy_traffic_df['dt'] prirnts dates from '2018-03-28' to '2018-09-14'

Comment: I need to be able to reproduce your problem. Please print the output of `print(df['dt'].iloc[[0, -1]].to_dict())` in your question please, otherwise no one can figure out what the problem is.

Comment: There can be whitespaces - follow cs95 's instruction so that we can see. @kaws

Comment: @cs95 added print(yoy_traffic_df['dt'].iloc[[0, -1]].to_dict())

Comment: Actually, it looks like your data is sorted in descending order of dates (the end date is earlier than the start). So just swap them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears `end_date` is earlier than `start_date`.

```
start_date = yoy_traffic_df['dt'].iloc[0]
end_date = yoy_traffic_df['dt'].iloc[-1]

start_date < end_date
# False
```

So the `date_range` turns up empty:

```
pd.date_range(start_date, end_date)
# DatetimeIndex([], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')
```

This is similar to how python's `range` works as well (`list(range(5, 1))` prints out an empty list). The best fix to do is to either call `min` or `max`,

```
start_date, end_date = yoy_traffic_df['dt'].min(), yoy_traffic_df['dt'].max()
```

Although if you specifically want the first and the end (not necessarily min or max), write some code to swap them.

```
if start_date > end_date:
    start_date, end_date = end_date, start_date
```